# How long my code loops inside this timer code?

Tags: java, random, timer

```
 static int N = 5;
 public static void randomN () {
      myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              public void run() {
                     if(N > 0)
               {
                   N--;
               }
               else myTimer.cancel();
...               
some math stuff in here like addition...
if ( N == 1 ) { 
                  System.out.println( a + requests"); }
      }, 0, 1000);
```

I get the result that I want with the code above. But I actually want my timer to go down from 30 seconds. And I want it to loop for 30 seconds. When trying that I noticed when I code if (requestTime == 0 ) and do the same stuff inside it I always get 2 prints. It is like my code is running just 1 more time before it stops. But when I do it with 1 it works perfectly except I am not sure if it gives me the result of working exactly 5 seconds or is it stop earlier than 5 seconds? And what is the reason that 0 is making a problem?

Comment: You've left out critical parts of the code, eg you've asked questions about requestTime but not included anything about it. The only thing I can think to tell you is that your task runs `N + 1` times because of your N > 0 logic. It runs from N to 0 so 6 times for N = 5. With a 0 initial delay, it runs for 5 seconds but there are 6 iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximately 5 seconds (plus or minus some unspecified and likely non-deterministic [jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter)) per the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) documentation because (at the start) `N = 5` and your `period = 1000` so `5000 milliseconds`. Try `N = 30` for 30 seconds. I have no idea what `requestTime` is.

Comment: Because when N (your counter) reaches 0, you cancel the Timer. I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking if the code in timer (...somestuffinhere...) is executed for 5 seconds if I use the code above. Is it executed 6 times if I change the if part like this if ( N == 0 ) @Elliott Frisch